# How to access all child <li> elements in a list in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have a html code that looks like the following:

```
<ul id="li1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li class="class1">f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

I want to traverse through each of the `<li>` element and check whether it has a specific class "`class1`". I am looking for something that look like (python-equivalent):

```
for i in $("#li1").children():
    print i.hasClass("class1")
```

I couldn't find a way to evaluate each of the child `<li>` element in javascript or jquery. Can someone help?

Comment: What do you wanna do? Just say if the LI has class or not is it?

Comment: I don't think that's valid markup.

Comment: [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Use something like $("li").children().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot nest `<li>` directly under `<li>`. That would be an invalid mark-up. Although, you may have something like this:

```
<ul id="li1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li class="class1">f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

So, for the above code, to get the same output, use this way:

```
$("#li1 li").each(function () {
  console.log($(this).hasClass("class1"));
});
```

This would print:

```
false
false
false
false
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

It building upon what Praveen has put you could also use the following just to loop through only those li tags that have the class

```js
$("#li1 li.class1").each(function () {
  console.log($(this).hasClass("class1"));
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're asking how to loop in *JavaScript*

Here is a way using [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) which stops at the index with a *falsy* value (i.e. `undefined`)

```
var i,                           // set up variables, 
    i_idx = 0,                   // initial index
    list = $("#li1").children(); // and interesting object

while (i = list[i++]) {
    console.log($(i).hasClass("class1"));
}
```

Here is a way using [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) which goes through all indicies by doing two things in the comparison expression space of the `for`

```
var list = $("#li1").children(); // interesting object

for (var i_idx = 0, i; i = list[i_idx], i_idx < list.length; ++i_idx) {
    console.log($(i).hasClass("class1"));
}
```

Here `i` is set using the index `i = list[i_idx]` and then the index is tested against the *length* `i_idx < list.length` in a single expression by making use of the *comma operator*

---

Please note

- a *jQuery Object's* indexed properties point to *native DOM objects*, which is why they need to be wrapped in `$(...)` to use in *jQuery* again.
- `while` and `for` etc do not provide `var` scope, the variables *`i`, `i_idx`, `list`* are scoped by their parent *function* (or the *global scope*)
- Generating `list` in the condition of a `while` or `for` will result in its regeneration every iteration. This is usually not desired which is why it is `var`d in advance.
- There are native methods for iterating *Array* (`.forEach`, `.map`, etc) and *jQuery* provides iterating methods too, but you may be unexpectedly caught out if you don't know where these are coming from (e.g. *Array-likes* such as *NodeList* do not always provide such a method)

---

### ES6

If you are working in an *EMCAScript 6* supported environment, you can use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which behaves much more as you had in the *python* example,

```
for (let i of $("#li1").children()) {
    console.log($(i).hasClass("class1"));
}
```